# How To Convert CloudFormation template to terraform code

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation

I have Cloudformation template something like this

```
Resources:

  WafValidHostsCondition:
    Type: AWS::WAF::ByteMatchSet
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AccountCode}-${RegionCode}-${Application}-waf-validhosts
      ByteMatchTuples:
        - FieldToMatch:
            Type: HEADER
            Data: host
          TargetString: !Ref PublicDns
          TextTransformation: NONE
          PositionalConstraint: EXACTLY

  WafValidHostsRule:
    Type: AWS::WAF::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AccountCode}-${RegionCode}-${Application}-waf-validhosts-rule
      MetricName: WafValidHostsRule
      Predicates:
        - DataId: !Ref WafValidHostsCondition
          Negated: true
          Type: ByteMatch

  WebAcl:
    Type: AWS::WAF::WebACL
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AccountCode}-${RegionCode}-${Application}-globalwebacl
      DefaultAction:
        Type: ALLOW
      MetricName: GlobalWebACL
      Rules:
        - Action:
            Type: BLOCK
          Priority: 1
          RuleId: !Ref WafValidHostsRule
```

And I wanna convert it to terraform code.
Yeah I can do it manually , but there are a lot :)
I don't wanna use `resource aws_cloudformation_stack`, because we are migrating all the stuff from cloudformation to terraform.
Also I have found this tool https://github.com/humanmade/cf-to-tf , but it work when I have existing CloudFormation Stack.
Is there any way to do it by script by tool or another way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if you find something, you'll also need to figure out how to convert the cloudformation state into Terraform state, which may not be directly possible. But I suppose having just the code converted would still make it easier to use the Terraform infra-to-state state import features.

Comment: I don't need state file, Because I will create it from 0.

Comment: Also @T.H. it helps with terraform import some features I can export. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Today I publicly released my side project `cf2tf` that does most of this work for you.

https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/cf2tf

I tried to convert your code but their was error

```
ValueError: Fn::Ref - AccountCode is not a valid Resource or Parameter.
```

Your example is obviously just part of the Cloudformation template.